# IronPython documentation by sphinx

Tags: ironpython, python-sphinx

Is it possible to document IronPython code with sphinx
or is there another tool to document IronPython code
Thanks
Ilan

Comment: It is probably possible to use Sphinx with IronPython (which is just another Python implementation). But currently the question is too vague.

Comment: I checked how to document an IronPython project with sphinx maybe one or two years ago. My conclusion was, that the least painful way was to write the code in a way that it was at least possible for CPython to import the modules and not to execute any acutal code (which is a problem if you want to use doctests). The .NET bits can be replaced with a generic mock object that returns itself for every operation. That way you should be able to run sphinx. I never had the pleasure to actually document the project but I experimented with that approach. If you are still interested, I can dig it up.